How to have multiple ports on Quarkus?
I realized I cannot set multiple ports in application.properties. Is there any way to set the multiple ports on Quarkus? I know I can set up multiple ports by reverse proxy, but I want "real" multiple ssl ports listening.

Afaik, this is not possible.
However, you can setup Nginx and configure multiple ports here and forward these to your Quarkus application.
Or you need to run multiple instances of your app on different ports.

Thanks for the comment. Is the reason impossible to set multiple ports due to Quarkus using netty by default? I'm using embedded tomcat and not quite sure why multiple ports are impossible for Quarkus.

@jjakjjak, I don’t see anything mentioned in the documentation about multiple ports. However, I see that Vertx supports multiple ports by starting up multiple http servers programmatically (vertx.createHttpServer).
